# How to initiate :hover when clicking on a separate link?

Tags: javascript, forms, hyperlink, hover

I'm trying to get my contact form to pop up when I click on "CONTACT" at the top of my site. My site URL is http://www.integritydesigns.com.

Right now the contact link at the top of my site links to an id (#contact) which is at the bottom of the page. The contact form currently only appears when you hover over the CONTACT US div (.dropdown) at the bottom right of the page. I'd like the form to appear when someone clicks on "CONTACT" in the top nav bar as well.

I'm sure it can be done with Javascript but I'm not sure where to start. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's cooler, the way it is now. However, you should set your "message" textarea to an absolute size because it's draggable right now and will go outside of the contact container.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I thought of that awhile back but completely neglected to initiate it. Instead of adjusting the size, you can simply put resize: none; using CSS. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It's not much that you want to initiate a "hover" from a separate location, it's that you want to "show a div" using two different triggers.

Look at the code you use to show the "contact" `<div>` when you hover. You can use the same kind of recipe with the link, but instead of an "onhover" trigger, use "onclick". You can set the "href" attribute of the link to "#".

Answer (score 0):

In the CONTACT click handler make the popup  visible. Probably, by assigning some css class to it.

Answer (score 0):

In your top menu link I'd put something like this `onclick="document.getElementById("form").style.display='block'"` (where `form` is an id given to your `ul` containing the form)

Of course if you want it to disappear if the user scrolls or clicks outside of it you'd have to set that up. (Hopefully others will offer suggestions for that as I myself have been wondering whats the best method to do that)